# Parse String of objects of stdClass in php

Tags: php, string, parsing, stdclass

I have a array of string of stdClass objects but i am not able to parse the string correctly

I have tried various methods but all gives the same error of "get property of non-object"

```
foreach($response->Product->$x as $prod)
{
print $prod->Name;
print $prod->Price;
print $prod->Stock;
print $prod->SupplierName;
print $prod->CategoryName;
$x++;
}
```

//But my string coming in response is

```
stdClass Object ( 
[Product] => Array 
( [0] => stdClass Object
( [Id] => 2 [Name] => Green Shirt [Price] => 1800 [Stock] => 50 [SupplierName] => Ali Yar [CategoryName] => Jeans )
  [1] => stdClass Object
  ( [Id] => 7 [Name] => Red Shirt with Flowers [Price] => 2200 [Stock] => 40 [SupplierName] => Ali Yar [CategoryName] => Shirt )
  [2] => stdClass Object
  ( [Id] => 8 [Name] => Red Shirt with Flowers [Price] => 2200 [Stock] => 40 [SupplierName] => Ali Yar [CategoryName] => Shirt ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object
  ( [Id] => 9 [Name] => Check Shirt Yellow [Price] => 1100 [Stock] => 200 [SupplierName] => Ali Yar [CategoryName] => Shirt 
  )
 )
 )
```

I am getting these errors  Trying to get property of non-object and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What is `$response->Product->$x`?

Comment: $response is the variable in which my response from java webservice is coming ... product as you can see is the stdClass object in my response ...

Comment: If `[Product]` __is__ `Array` then using `->` is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Product` property is array, then:

```
foreach($response->Product as $prod)
{

    print $prod->Name;
    print $prod->Price;
    print $prod->Stock;
    print $prod->SupplierName;
    print $prod->CategoryName;

    // this increment is useless
    //$x++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clear but i think you have to edit the `foreach` in this

```
foreach($response->Product as $prod)
{
print $prod->Name;
print $prod->Price;
print $prod->Stock;
print $prod->SupplierName;
print $prod->CategoryName;
$x++;
}
```